# Asus BT500 not working on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: bluetooth

I got a Asus BT500 dongle that I want to use in my Thinkpad laptop but it seems like the Bluetooth drivers keep crashing when I start it up. I have some information:

```
peter@peter-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-3:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

```
peter@peter-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-3:~$ uname -r
5.15.0-27-generic
```

```
peter@peter-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-3:~$ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0bda:c123 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Bluetooth Radio
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 04f3:0c4b Elan Microelectronics Corp. ELAN:Fingerprint
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 046d:c539 Logitech, Inc. USB Receiver
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b6be Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd Integrated Camera
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0b05:190e ASUSTek Computer, Inc. ASUS USB-BT500
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

As you can see the `ASUSTek Computer, Inc. ASUS USB-BT500` is found. I've followed these steps: https://github.com/ARMmbed/connectedhomeip/wiki/Using-Asus-BT500-bluettoth-dongle-on-Linux-system

dmesg output:

```
peter@peter-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-3:~$ sudo dmesg | grep -i blue
[    2.440485] usb 3-4: Product: Bluetooth Radio
[    5.265861] systemd[1]: Mounting Mount unit for bluetooth-autostart, revision 10...
[    5.267028] systemd[1]: Mounting Mount unit for bluez, revision 302...
[    5.517771] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    5.517973] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[    5.517975] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    5.517979] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    5.517981] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    5.517986] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    5.562662] thinkpad_acpi: rfkill switch tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: radio is unblocked
[    8.619604] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    8.619607] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    8.619610] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   12.100922] audit: type=1400 audit(1652691293.168:120): apparmor="DENIED" operation="create" profile="snap.bluetooth-autostart.autostart-bluetooth" pid=1373 comm="hciconfig" family="bluetooth" sock_type="raw" protocol=1 requested_mask="create" denied_mask="create"
```

Comment: Please add output of `dnesg | grep -i blue` to your question. And why don't you use the in-built BT device?

Comment: @Pilot6 I've updated the question. I was using the build in BT, but had some issues like when I connected both my headset and keyboard, my headset would disconnect or drop in quality and I would need to reconnect my keyboard after it hadn't been used for a bit. I hoped the BT500 would resolve those issues.

Answer (score 0):

A colleague recommended to `sudo apt-get upgrade` which updated a lot of *stuff*, which fixed my issue.